# Accessing someone else's Google Calendar in Android

Tags: java, android, google-calendar-api

I'm developing an Android application (2.3+) for my university club. Our club makes use of Google Apps for calendar, e-mail, etc. One of the accounts hosts the calendar for all of our club's upcoming events.

In my application I would like to query this calendar so I can display events coming up in the next week or month. I have access to the "magic cookie" address of the calendar.

Every tutorial/example I've seen thus far gives directions for accessing the user's calendar. How do I use the calendar API to access a calendar that *isn't* the user's?

Answer (score 0):

The super administrator of the domain has access to all users' calendar and calendar events details.

http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33326